# How to add the checkbox item at the new line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox list like below:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList  id="chx" runat="server" repeatdirection="Horizontal"> <asp:ListItem value="OPTION1">Option 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem value="OPTION2">Option 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem value="OPTION3">Option 3</asp:ListItem><
asp:ListItem value="OPTION4">Option 4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And I am dynamically adding the list items to this checkbox using the following C# code:

```
chx.Items.Clear();
while(dr.Read()){
    if(dr.GetOracleString(0).ToString()!="Null"){
        chx.Items.Add(dr.GetOracleString(0).ToString());
    }
}
```

My requirement is whenever the new item is added in the checkboxlist, it should check whether the new item is going beyond the border(fixed width) of the page and if so the new item should go the next line of checkboxlist without **overlapping below control**.
Please help me to fix this.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the property `RepeatColumns`

```
RepeatColumns="3"
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Because a CheckBox list is rendered as an HTML table. Therefore it cannot be wrapped unless you reduce the no of columns (TDs in HTML).

Comment: @Sam, it's only rendered as an HTML table if you leave the `RepeatLayout` on it's default setting (`"Table"`). You can also set `RepeatLayout="Flow"` to use `<span>` elements, `="OrderedList"` to use `<ol>` elements, and `="UnorderedList"` to use `<ul>` elements.